# What is the API used by IE to remember proxy credentials?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, credentials

Those ever working with the Internet Explorer know this dialog:
[image]

My question is what is the API used to remember the credentials when the respective check box is ticked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess, it's [CredUIStoreSSOCredW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375181%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  The actual prompt comes from 
[CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375178%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).